# How can I get part of a dataframe name and make it a column in R?

Tags: r

I have a list of dataframes in my R environment, *e.g.* `phenotype1_acbd`, `phenotype2_qwert`, etc.

For each data frame, I want to get the phenotype name from the data frame's name and add it as a column in that data frame. For example, the data frame `phenotype1_acbd` will get a new `Phenotype` column:

```r
Col1  Phenotype
 1    phenotype1
 2    phenotype1
```

How do I create the column `Phenotype` in R using data frame's name?

I know the phenotypes I want from the dataframes, *e.g.*

```r
phenotypes <- c('phenotype1', 'phenotype2')
```

Can I use this to match to my dataframe names, then create the column in the correct dataframe for all of my dataframes?

Comment: Could you explain the rationale behind `Col1` column? Also, could you please confirm if if the variables that store data frames have `_` in them *i.e.* do all data frame have `X_Y` names with `X` representing phenotypes?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mget()` to get the data frames from your environment and some tools from the {purrr} package to filter that list down to include only data frames and combine them:

```r
phenotype1 <- data.frame(x = 1, y = 1)
phenotype2 <- data.frame(x = 2, y = 2, z = 3)

mget(c("phenotype1", "phenotype2")) |>
  purrr::list_rbind(names_to = "phenotype")
```

This is not a great approach - if possible it would be better to store your data frames in a list, which would make the `mget()` step redundant.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can create a matching pattern for the phenotypes of interest:

```
phe_match <- paste(phenotypes, collapse = "|")
```

And it sounds like you have your data.frames in a list, here I created a simple example:

```
old_lst <- list(
  phenotype1_acbd = data.frame(col1 = 1:2),
  phenotype2_qwert = data.frame(col1 = 1:3),
  phenotype3_uiop = data.frame(col1 = 1:4)
)
```

You can use `imap` through your data.frames, check the name of each data.frame with your pattern. If the string is detected, then add a column containing the match; otherwise just keep the data.frame

```
library(tidyverse)

new_lst <- imap(
  old_lst, 
  ~ if (str_detect(.y, phe_match)) 
    mutate(.x, Phenotype = str_match(.y, phe_match)) 
  else .x)

new_lst
```

**Output**

```
$phenotype1_acbd
  col1  Phenotype
1    1 phenotype1
2    2 phenotype1

$phenotype2_qwert
  col1  Phenotype
1    1 phenotype2
2    2 phenotype2
3    3 phenotype2

$phenotype3_uiop
  col1
1    1
2    2
3    3
4    4
```